# Recommended Post Structure for DB Storage

Tags: database, post-meta

I'm trying to write a plugin that would help my local little league manage their league, and though I've read the [New Table vs Post Meta](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4852/post-meta-vs-seperate-database-tables) question, it's still a bit unclear and I'm hoping someone here might be able to help.

I have the CPT's (Teams, Players and Matches) as well as the taxonomies (seasons, divisions and positions) created, but my main concern is historical data and querying that data.

Is the best way to store player statistics and things of that nature in a separate database table? Is there a scenario anyone could envision where storing that in post_meta would be superior?

Comment: My take on the new-tables-or-no-new-tables question is here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77511/custom-database-or-custom-post-types/77577#77577

Answer (score 0):

It's almost always superior to use the standard WP tables. All WP functionality and plugins 'know' about those tables, and have access to them. They are completely oblivious to custom-built tables.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I guess my concern is primarily focused on the historical aspect of the data. As a player changes teams and divisions, changing the associated taxonomies would change all the historical data with it, would it not?